# Run Bootstrap Modal on jQuery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi guys I'm just wondering how to call my bootstrap modal in jquery 1.4.4 I get error but when I was in jquery 1.11.0 it works fine. Here:

```
$('#confirm-submit').modal('show');
```

Comment: what error do you get? Is their a reasen why you have to use jQuery 1.4.4?

Comment: Time to upgrade your JQuery?

Comment: The Company requires it :( I have no choice.

Comment: If its Bootstrap 3 you are using, I think the minimum jQuery version required is 1.9.  Odd decision if your company is ok to use bootstrap but not a modern version of jQuery.

Comment: I have no other choice, so that means I will not be able to use bootstrap modal anymore?

Comment: I have the same problem as @JoeneFloresca. Can there be any other alternative to this. I mean any free plugin for the popup. The popup needs to be responsive as bootstrap popup.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you guys have solved it?